# interfaces/static IP problem - Debian

Tags: linux, debian, static-ip, interface

I'm trying to configure my Debian machine (Lenny) to use a static ip address. Here's what my interfaces file currently looks like:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system.
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces

#The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.200
network 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Here's what I've done. I went in to my router settings and changed it's dynamic ip range to 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.100. So I could use anything above 100 as my static address. Then I came in to the interfaces file and edited to what you see above. I set the address to be 192.168.1.200 because that's out of the range that's reserved for dynamic addresses by my router and I also set the network to 192.168.1.1 because that's the ip address of my router.

I'm not sure what i'm getting wrong but I have no connection to the internet. I'm not sure i've got the right IP addresses.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add "gateway 192.168.1.1" and change the network entry to "network 192.168.1.0".

Comment: Actually, he can go ahead and get rid of the network statement. It is only required for ancient kernels.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I've done what you suggested. restarted the machine and noticed that on startup there was a message saying:

    configuring network interfaces..../etc/network/interfaces:11: duplicate interfaces
    Ifup: Couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"

So i went in to the network dirctory did a ls -a and there was a file called interfaces~ with exactly the same content. I removed it and re-booted but still have this message on startup. Double checked and there's only one interfaces file with the correct text in it. Any ideas?

Comment: whoops my bad. Somehow an extra line of text was in the file
    iface eth0 inet static
It works now :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add the below configuration also.

Open /etc/resolv.conf.
In it use the nameserver directive to specify your name server(s). The nameserver directive(s) will be searched in the order entered here. Here is an example:
nameserver 192.168.1.2
nameserver 192.168.1.3